# How to set global/specific properies when updating line-chart using Chart.js?

Tags: linechart, chart.js

this is my situation http://jsfiddle.net/co3L0bdb/4/

thanks to @potatopeelings help i am now able to set the property `highlightFill` to all my `datasets` and this works even when I show/hide a series in the graph.
I added:

```
currentChart.datasets[0].points[8].highlightStroke = "rgba(220,0,0,1)";
currentChart.datasets[1].points[8].highlightStroke = "rgba(0,255,0,1)";
currentChart.datasets[2].points[8].highlightStroke = "rgba(0,0,255,1)";
```

but what i get, **but i do not want**, is that when I hide a series, after 2 iteration it starts to plot the hidden data and stops to remove the firsts data of the series.
How can I set even series-spefic properties, such as `highlightStroke`, without the described side effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the dataset property to an empty object, just don't include it in the dataset at all. So

> ```
> data = {
>     labels: chartlabel,
>     datasets: [SP, NC, SPA]
> };
> ```

becomes

```
data = {
    labels: chartlabel,
    datasets: []
};

if (SP.label !== undefined) data.datasets.push(SP)
if (NC.label !== undefined) data.datasets.push(NC)
if (SPA.label !== undefined) data.datasets.push(SPA)
```

in 2 places

---

Replace the data insertion, point attribute setting by a loop (instead of hardcoding it for 3 datasets). So

> ```
> setInterval(function() {
>     currentChart.addData([randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()], ++latestLabel);
> currentChart.datasets[0].points[8].highlightStroke = "rgba(220,0,0,1)";
> currentChart.datasets[1].points[8].highlightStroke = "rgba(0,255,0,1)";
> currentChart.datasets[2].points[8].highlightStroke = "rgba(0,0,255,1)";
> ```

becomes

```
var d = []
currentChart.datasets.forEach(function(e) {
    d.push(randomScalingFactor())
})
currentChart.addData(d, ++latestLabel);
currentChart.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    dataset.points[8].highlightStroke = dataset.points[0].highlightStroke;
})
```

The highlightStroke for the new point is copied from the highlightStroke for the first point of the same series.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zs99pw4L/

Comment: Thanks again,
your solution works, but i actually solved the problem in the way i posted as reply

Answer (score 0):

```
currentChart2.datasets.forEach(function(e) {
    e.points[e.points.length - 1].highlightFill=e.points[0].highlightFill;
    e.points[e.points.length - 1].highlightStroke=e.points[0].highlightStroke;
});
```

Solves the problem too.
http://jsfiddle.net/co3L0bdb/5/

Comment: Cheers! btw with this, the points start building up once you remove a series - that what you wanted? And it kind of compresses horizontally once you add a series back after removing it.

Comment: You are right, i do not want this, this code is just an exampe in my real application adding that line works fine.

Comment: Ah ok that explains it.